# Как компилировать файлы проекта под платформу?

Tags: c++, c++builder, radstudio, кроссплатформенность

Использую RAD Studio XE8. Есть проект под Win и Android.

Можно ли настроить компиляцию так, чтобы `unit` или `.cpp` не компилировались под Android, но компилировались для Win и наоборот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Не уверен что прям получиться "исключить", но сильно "уменьшить" точно. (у меня нет делфи под рукой - не могу все проверить).

Метод будет работать начиная с XE5.

В делфи давно уже есть комментарии специального вида, которые работают как директивы условной компиляции. И согласно [этому документу](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)) можно определять компиляцию под андроид. То есть, если нужно, что бы определенный кусок кода компилировался только под андроид, пишем так

```
// эта строка будет компилировать и работать везде
{$IF ANDROID}
//только под адндроидом
{$ENDIF }
// и снова везде.
```

А можно и так

```
// работает везде
{$IF ANDROID}
// только под адроид
{$ELSE}
// везде кроме андроида
{$ENDIF}
// снова везде
```

Таким образом можно исключать/добавлять нужные куски кода. На github я даже нашел пример [кода](https://github.com/remobjects/EUnit/blob/c4d17da6fd57d006bf37f486e1a1e6496a0f4d96/Sources/Discovery/Discovery.pas).

Под с++ должно работать с `#ifdef`, классически.

А теперь, по поводу "можно ли вообще убрать файл с компиляции". Думаю, что если в dproj (или как теперь называется файл проекта?) такими директивами прибрать файл, то все должно выйти. Но я не уверен.

Comment: Да, все верно, я уже сам нашел это :)
Чтобы убрать файл, нужно его просто исключить из проекта. ПКМ по файлу и выбираем `Exclude from build`